# Parsing from a stream of XML string fragment in Python

Tags: python, xml, string, data-stream

I have an eye-tracker uses TCP/IP communication and XML to send data between client (application) and server (eye-tracker).  The following is an example of the XML data string I receive continuously while the eye-tracker is on. What I would like to do is be able to use the data, FPOGX and FPOGY, as an input to another function I have.  The problem is they are not variables and you can't just simply call upon them.  How do I parse this data stream? This is the first time I've worked with XML.  Examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
CLIENT SEND: <SET ID="ENABLE_SEND_COUNTER" STATE="1" />
SERVER SEND: <ACK ID="ENABLE_SEND_COUNTER" STATE="1" />
CLIENT SEND: <SET ID="ENABLE_SEND_POG_FIX" STATE="1" />
SERVER SEND: <ACK ID="ENABLE_SEND_POG_FIX" STATE="1" />
CLIENT SEND: <SET ID="ENABLE_SEND_DATA" STATE="1" />
SERVER SEND: <ACK ID="ENABLE_SEND_DATA" STATE="1" />
SERVER SEND: <REC CNT="72" FPOGX="0.5065" FPOGY="0.4390"
FPOGD="0.078" FPOGID="468" FPOGV="1"/>
SERVER SEND: <REC CNT="73" FPOGX="0.5071" FPOGY="0.4409"
FPOGD="0.094" FPOGID="468" FPOGV="1"/>
SERVER SEND: <REC CNT="74" FPOGX="0.5077" FPOGY="0.4428"
FPOGD="0.109" FPOGID="468" FPOGV="1"/>
```

Here is a snippet of some parts of the code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import cv2
import cv
import socket

# Code to grab different data from eye-tracker
'...'
# Code to create window and initialize camera
'...'
def xmlParse():
    rxdat = s.recv(1024)  # Syntax from eye-tracker to grab XML data stream of <REC />
    if(rxdat.find("ACK") == 1):  # First two XML have the <ACK /> tag but I don't need those
        pass
    else: # Here is the part where it parses and converts the data to float
        rxdat = '<data>' + rxdat + '</data>' 
        xml = ET.fromstring(rxdat)
        for element in xml:
            X = float(xml[0].attrib['FPOGX'])
            Y = float(xml[0].attrib['FPOGY'])
        return (X, Y)

# Def to average samples of incoming X and Y
'...'
# Def that uses xmlParse() and average() to return the averages of X and Y
'...'
# Def for mouse click events
'...'
# Some code that makes our window graphics
'...'
for i in range(0,2):    # Round-about way to get rid of the first two "NoneType"
    xmlParse()

while True:
    Img = cv.QueryFrame(capture) # capture defined earlier
    drawarrow(polyF, polyB, polyL, polyR) # Our window graphics definition
    cv.ShowImage("window", Img)
    (X, Y) = gazeCoordinates() # Def that uses xmlParse and average to return the averages of X and Y
    if cv.WaitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error given is `ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)` and points to the `xml = ET.fromstring(rxdat)` of the code

The definition xmlParse() by itself and just printing out the results works. But once I start adding in the windows, graphics, and using the data, it starts giving out that error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't need to parse all of the text above (which is not properly xml when taken all together) but rather just a single xml element at a time, I would suggest trying something like the following. You will end up with a dictionary of attributes, which contain the key/value pairs you are after.

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> xml_string = '<REC CNT="72" FPOGX="0.5065" FPOGY="0.4390" FPOGD="0.078" FPOGID="468" FPOGV="1"/>'
>>> xml = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
>>> xml.attrib  # a dict
{'CNT': '72', 'FPOGV': '1', 'FPOGY': '0.4390', 'FPOGX': '0.5065', 'FPOGD': '0.078', 'FPOGID': '468'}
>>> xml.attrib['FPOGX'], xml.attrib['FPOGY']
('0.5065', '0.4390')
```

You can check out the documentation for xml.etree.ElementTree [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

**EDIT**

Regarding your comment, you could try to wrap your string in an xml element before parsing it in order to code around any `junk` that might be included after (or before) the xml. For example, you could try this (note the "junk" that I have added to the end of the first xml string):

```
>>> xml_string = '<REC CNT="72" FPOGX="0.5065" FPOGY="0.4390" FPOGD="0.078" FPOGID="468" FPOGV="1"/>here is some junk that should not be here and that does not fit into xml.'
>>> xml_string = '<data>' + xml_string + '</data>'  # makes sure that the xml has an outer tag
>>> xml = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
>>> for element in xml:  # now need to iterate through <data> tag
    print element.attrib  # a dict
    {'CNT': '72', 'FPOGV': '1', 'FPOGY': '0.4390', 'FPOGX': '0.5065', 'FPOGD': '0.078', 'FPOGID': '468'}
>>> xml[0].attrib['FPOGX'], xml[0].attrib['FPOGY']  # or you can find attributes by indices (like a list)
    ('0.5065', '0.4390')
```

**EDIT 2**

Your Python looks just fine. The problem is with a character (or characters) that you are receiving in the xml string. (The `<data></data>` element is also fine.) You could figure out which token is giving you trouble by replacing this:

```
xml = ET.fromstring(rxdat)
```

with this:

```
try:
    xml = ET.fromstring(rxdat)
except:
    print rxdat  # will print the string or strings it cannot parse
```

You may need to escape a character or group of characters, depending on what you find out from this test.

Comment: This would give me the error 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jenny\Desktop\Team Design\GazeXMLtest.py", line 26, in <module>
    xml = ET.fromstring(rxdat)
  File "<string>", line 124, in XML
ParseError: junk after document element: line 2, column 0`
most of the times.  Sometimes it will run perfectly and then sometimes it would run and give the error at a later time.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @user3121062 You can try to add a wrapper around the data before you parse the xml. I will update the answer with an example in just a moment.

Comment: @user3121062 I updated the answer, which might help catch the "junk".

Comment: Thanks for responding super fast. That worked perfectly, until we combined it to our main code and then it started giving this error `ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)` most of the times.  We are using it along with opencv, might that have something to do with it?

Comment: @user3121062 Can you post the relevant code (where you are adding this data to your main script) to your question?

Comment: Added a snippet of the code. Let me know if any of those that I commented out would be relevant to the error.

Comment: @user3121062 I added a second edit to my answer. I offered a means for troubleshooting the xml. The Python code is fine; the problem is with the xml, and you can probably discover that problem using the test I suggest above in edit 2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45560/discussion-between-user3121062-and-275365)